# "Include" one javascript file to another one

Tags: javascript

I have 2 separate javascript files

```
#1.js
String.prototype.format = ....
String.prototype.capitalize = ....

#2.js

//................
var text = "some text{0}".format(var1)
//................
```

How do I make `string#format` and `string#capitalize` available in the second file?

Comment: In what environment? A browser? Command-line? A server?

Comment: This has been asked and answered ***several*** times now, [notably here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file), just look at the "Related" list on the right (it would also have been "pushed" at you when you were asking the question).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

JavaScript executes globally. Adding both scripts on the page makes them available to each other as if they were in one file.

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
```

However, you should note that JavaScript is parsed "linearly" and thus, "first parsed, first served". If the first script needs something in the second script, but the second script hasn't been parsed yet, it will result in an error.

If that happens, you should rethink your script structure.