# What does this line in javascript in html mean?

Tags: javascript, html

What does this line in javascript mean? Its located in an html file

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Include" one javascript file to another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135718/include-one-javascript-file-to-another-one)

Comment: This would be covered in almost literally *any* HTML tutorial/guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your browser renders the HTML code, it stops at your mentioned line, makes a GET request for the file (relative path => `Current address + js/main.js`) and will then parse the main.js file.

After that the browser will continue to render the HTML and after that execute, what's in `main.js`.

It is the default way to include Javascript files to a website.

Answer (score 1):

It adds the main.js file which is under js folder to your html file. Now you can use its methods in your javascript code

Answer (score 0):

indicates which javscript file is included in the html page